# Is there a way to bind OGNL with Struts2 UI tags

Tags: java, session, struts2, ognl, valuestack

I'm developing a webapp using Struts2. I used to work with Struts1

is there a way to reference a session object directly to the JSP so that if I change the value in the formular, the value in the referenced session object will also be updated.

```
<s:textfield name="%{#session.order.amount}"/>
```

for e.g. I have a session object order which has attribute amount with getter and setter.

it seems like, after I put some values into the `textfield` and then submit the page, the value in the session didn't get updated.

currently I'm using another approach which involves `session.put()` inside the setter of an action attributes. Personally I dislike my current solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try having the name be the *string* `session.order.amount` and make your action implement SessionAware, and expose the session. Currently you're setting the name to the *value* of `session.order.amount`.

I don't know if it would work, and you might need to use array/collection notation, but off the top of my head I don't know why it *wouldn't* work.

That said, I feel like direct view-layer *writes* into web app internals is a Bad Idea.

Comment: thank you for your reply

I could retrieve the values from the session using the OGNL syntax that I wrote in my initial post. 

but somehow it won't set value from the from into the session.

I guess struts2 make a clone copy of the value instead of referencing to the object from the session.

Comment: @raito I seriously doubt it makes a clone, but I have no problem believing it didn't work, which is a good thing-this is a *terrible* practice. Spooky action at a distance should be left to quantum physics.

Answer (score 1):

From the Struts1 where form bean placed to the session scope by default or just by setting an attribute value `scope="session"` and everything was good.

In the Struts2 you have not form beans nor *session scoped* beans. And to use *session scoped* beans you need to either implement it yourself, or use other frameworks like Spring, Guice or CDI where *session scoped* is implemented and available to user.

On the other hand Struts2 is in heavy use of interceptors, which provide you additional features like [`scope` interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/scope-interceptor.html), or [`scopedModelDriven` interceptor](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/scoped-model-driven-interceptor.html) that allows you to put some action properties to the session scope. It will initialize the properties each time the action is executed referencing objects are put on the session scope.

Without this helper interceptors you could always intercept a session object by implementing `SessionAware` (see [How do we get access to the session](https://struts.apache.org/docs/how-do-we-get-access-to-the-session.html)) and initialize the properties somewhere when the action is executed, i.e. [`prepare()`](https://struts.apache.org/docs/prepare-interceptor.html) method, because it's comming after the session map is injected. Putting initializer to the accessors is a bad idea.

Comment: thank you for your reply, however we are not planning to use another framework. Using interceptor to retrieve the values from the action and put it into session was already considered, it still involves double work.

Comment: @raito Other frameworks, mentioned above are integrated into Struts2 via plugins, it simply a reasonable extension. But if you strictly stick with the Struts2 you might find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244036/dependency-injection-in-struts2-accessing-session-scoped-beans) solution as an option.

Comment: As Dave mentioned all you need is SessionAware, you can most certainly add and modify session attributes that way.

Comment: @Quaternion, you can access the session variable through ServletActionContext as well.

btw our solution atm is putting the object to the session in setter

Comment: @ratio You *can*, but it decreases testability, and SessionAware is the recommended practice.