# Struts 2 bean configuration default scope

Tags: java, spring, struts2, dependency-injection, scope

I'm trying to use basic DI with Struts2 using the configuration file as described [here](http://struts.apache.org/docs/bean-configuration.html).

However, I was not able to find what the default scope is for injecting a bean.

I know that the default scope is Singleton for Spring but I didn't want to assume the same with Struts2.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are wise in not assuming the default scope for struts2. I can't come to a conclusion either. Maybe this thread helps: http://struts.1045723.n5.nabble.com/Spring-Scope-Default-td3489074.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default scope is `singleton`, but there's a scope with name `default` which is different. May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244036/dependency-injection-in-struts2-accessing-session-scoped-beans) question let you better understand scopes in Struts2. The framework support scopes like `singleton`, `default`, and `thread` other scopes you should implement manually.

Look at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts.xwork/xwork-core/2.3.15.1/com/opensymphony/xwork2/config/providers/XmlConfigurationProvider.java#198) where the scopes are defined.

To clarify the scope named `default` means a *one instance per injection*. You can find this in comments to [Scope.DEFAULT](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts.xwork/xwork-core/2.3.15.1/com/opensymphony/xwork2/inject/Scope.java?av=f).

Comment: I'm confused by your answer little bit. Do you mean if I don't specify scope at all, it injects a singleton, but if I explicitly specify scope as `scope="default"` then it's different?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still unclear to me how the `scope="default"` would behave.

Comment: It will create a new instance per injection.

Comment: @Mustafa I've added this to the answer.