# Struts2/Hibernate update few columns without having other column data

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, struts2

I have an object with 3 fields but only 2 of them are shown on the screen for the user to update.

```
class Person {
    Integer id;
    String lastName;
    String firstName;
    Date   birthDate;
    . . . 
    getters/setters
}
```

My action object contains the Person object with getter and setters :

```
class myAction {
    Person person;

    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }
    public Person getPerson() {
        return this.person;
    }
}
```

And my JSP uses struts2 to link the 2 fields to this object with this:

```
<p/>Enter your first name <s:textfield name="person.lastName"/>
<p/>Enter your Last name  <s:textfield name="person.firstName"/>
<button id="btnSave">Save changes</button>
```

So when the button is clicked, struts fills in a new Person object and my action class has access to this new object to update the DB. The problem is this NEW object has ONLY the 2 fields that were on the screen filled in. The other attributes that weren't displayed are lost, When trying to use Hibernate to update the object it returns an exception that a non-nullable value is NULL.

I looked at dynamic-update=true which says :

```
specifies that UPDATE SQL should be generated at runtime and can contain only 
those columns whose values have changed.
```

and that sounds better (why would anyone want to update columns that havent changed???) but is still doesnt work because struts2 created a NEW object, which doesn't have the rest of the attributes.

In my action class I shouldn't have to select the object (again), set new values from what struts2 filled in and then update the object. I also shouldn't have to write special HQL update statements to only update the columns that exist on the screen.

So how can I get around this? Is there a way to hold onto the original object (from the action going into the screen) when the query was done, update is with the users changes and 'send' that exact object to the submit action again so the object retains the other data not shown on the screen? Or can I tell Hibernate to ignore null fields and just update fields that have values in the object?

Answer (score 0):

The Hibernate is managing your objects, all you need is to save `id` of the object somewhere in the scope that has a lifecycle that occupies more than one http request, and then use that `id` to get the object from the Hibernate session.

At least two requests needed to make edit of an existed object: one is for retrieving the object and display on the form, another is for submitting the form and updating the object.

Because you object is a member of the action bean which has a default scope, you always have to initialize the property of your object if you have a reference to the object. You can of course change the scope of your action bean to a session, or better, use the scope of your object to the session using scope interceptors, or using injection like in this question [Dependency Injection in Struts2 Accessing Session Scoped Beans](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17244036/573032) (You can use any DI framework that is configured with Struts2).

And you can get this object from the scope, I mean `id` of the object, get the persistent object from the Hibernate session by this `id`, modify its properties and pass back to Hibernate for update.