# Using Fortify SCA with Struts 2 and Spring

Tags: java, spring, struts2, fortify

I'm using HP Fortify SCA and Apps 4.20 for my project which used Struts2 spring Hibernate.
The report said my project has

```
Race Condition: Singleton Member Field
```

problem with the controllers.

However, Struts2 is thread safe, because it create a new instance when a new request come.
Furthermore, I set spring annotation in the controller

```
@Controller
@Scope("request")
```

I don't know how to solve this problem.
Did it misjudge, or there are problem with my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Struts2 is threadsafe, because it creates a new action instance per request.

But it's not request scoped. (If you want to implement request scope strategy in Struts2 you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17244036/573032) question.)

Instead, it uses a `default` scope for the action instance. If Struts2 is integrated with Spring the scope of the action bean you should define using Spring configuration. By default spring is using a `singleton` scope.

This could be a source for your problem with race condition. Because you accessing a singleton member field.

If you delegate to Spring to manage your action beans, then you should use `prototype` scope.

Also don't use Spring-MVC annotations like `@Controller`, it has less meaning to Struts2. The `@Component` is enough to enable DI capability.

Answer (score 0):

Race condition can be caused by instance member in servlet, which must be thread safe.  If this is the case, move offending member to method to render thread-safe.