# Scopes in Struts 2 and standards for them

Tags: struts2, scope

How many scopes are there in Struts 2 applications? And is it good if we use session and request scope there? How action scope work for session and request both?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. An S2 app is still a servlet-spec artifact, so the standard JEE scopes are there. S2 adds another "scope", the value stack, although it's implemented in terms of the only scopes available, the JEE-defined scopes.

Comment: @DaveNewton so how request and session scopes are different from value stack(Action Scope?)

Comment: The value stack is where s2 puts its data. The value stack is contained within a JEE score (request I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Struts 2 is running a container, it has scopes for beans. More about bean scopes is in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17244036/573032) question. All other scopes are servlet scopes. Struts uses indirect access to these scopes using it's own structures. For example a `set` tag uses these scopes:

> The scopes available are as follows :
>
> ```
> application - the value will be set in application scope according to servlet spec. using the name as its key
> session - the value will be set in session scope according to servlet spec. using the name as key
> request - the value will be set in request scope according to servlet spec. using the name as key
> page - the value will be set in page scope according to servlet sepc. using the name as key
> action - the value will be set in the request scope and Struts' action context using the name as key
> ```
>
> NOTE:
>
> If no scope is specified, it will default to action scope.

Comment: can we use Action Scope to handle sessions.?

Comment: yes you can, because action scope is a smaller scope than a session scope.