# make object session in struts2 with spring may be

Tags: java, struts2

I have the logonForm object in two action class (MemberAction, AccountOverviewAction). I want to make logonForm as session scope variable in struts2 in these two action class. But when open this view page, it throws below exception. Is there anything I have missing? On the other hand, i do not find struts2 web project mentioning about object as session scope example. I not mention session in http. If you know example, could you please give me the url?

```
    Unable to instantiate Action, memberAction, defined for 'membersite' in 
namespace
'/secure'com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MissingDependencyException
: No mapping found for dependency [type=com.awip.struts.actionform.LogonForm, 
name='session'] in private com.awip.struts.actionform.LogonForm 
com.awip.struts.action.MemberAction.logonForm. - action -
```

LogonForm Bean

```
@Repository
@Scope("session")
public class LogonForm extends ActionSupport {
```

Action Class

```
public class MemberAction extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware{

@Inject("session")
private LogonForm logonForm;
```

2 Action Class

```
public class AccountOveriewAction extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware{

    @Inject("session")
    private LogonForm logonForm;
```

ApplicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="logonForm" class="com.awip.struts.actionform.LogonForm" scope="session"/>  // it seems useless of this line ???
<bean id="memberAction" class="com.awip.struts.action.MembersiteAction" />
```

struts.xml

```
<action name="membersite" method="displayMembersiteMain" class="memberAction">
            <result name="displayMembersiteMain" type="tiles">.membersite.Main</result>
```

Comment: where's your code?

Comment: My coding for session in struts2 may be wrong. As it is my first time to code struts. I have seen struts2 tutorial but I do not find the example of my case.

Comment: Even if I find, e.g. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244036/dependency-injection-in-struts2-accessing-session-scoped-beans?rq=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244036/dependency-injection-in-struts2-accessing-session-scoped-beans?rq=1) but it does not help.

Comment: I have done another test. Even with ServletActionContext.getRequest(). the session variables also become disappeared and null after redirect to another page.

Comment: Pointless, there's no a form bean in Struts2, you should create and instantiate objects yourself or via any DI framework like Spring. This question and answer was an attempt to implement session scoped beans in Struts2 using internal DI (not documented and discouraged yet).